# React: Trasform submit button on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my render I have:

```
render(){
 return (
//.....

<this.Content>

//...
```

in Content I have all the parts that I show to user and at the end I have:

```
Content = props => {
return(
//..

   <Submit
            onSubmit={self.props.handleSubmit(values => self._onSubmit(values))}
            />
)}
```

Now my problem is when the submit button has clicked I would to change it with:

```
<Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" />
```

How can I do?

EDIT.

```
 constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
         wasButtonClicked: false,
    }

  Content = props => {
    return(
     //
          {this.state.wasButtonClicked == true ? <Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" /> : <Submit   onSubmit={self.props.handleSubmit(values => {this.setState({wasButtonClicked: true}),self._onSubmit(values)})}   />}
            />
    }


render() {
return(
//
  this.state.HasEmail === true
              ?
              <this.Content />
              :
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using JSX you can:

1. Create a state `wasButtonClicked` and initiate it with false.
2. onclick of the button `setState` `wasButtonClicked` to true
3. Insted of rendering the button call `{this.renderItem()}`
4. Create the function:

   ```
   renderItem = () => {
   return this.state.wasButtonClicked ? <Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" /> : <YourBUttonELement/>
   }
   ```

Comment: I have edited my code, i don't understand how to put the 3 and 4 points

Comment: Are you using jsx?

Comment: No I'm using .js

Answer (score 0):

Steps to implement with your code in a simple language

1. You have added `wasButtonClicked` in `this.state`.
2. Use ternary condition in the `return` of your `Content` function. If `wasButtonClicked` is `true` then return `<Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" />`, on `false` return `Submit` button.
3. `OnClick` of your submit button `setState` `wasButtonClicked` to true.
4. `setState` `wasButtonClicked` to false whenever your required operation completed.

Style the `Spinner` wrap it inside a `div` or way suitable to look similar to the button

EDITED

Use this instead of your `Content` function

```
Content = props => {
    return (
        this.state.wasButtonClicked
            ? <Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" />
            : <Submit onSubmit={() => self.props.handleSubmit(values => {
                this.setState({ wasButtonClicked: true });
                self._onSubmit(values);
            })} />
    )
}
```

I don't know what is `self` referred to in your code is it the `this` keyword you are using here. I made your code syntactically correct.

Comment: I have tried (I edited my question) but when I click on button the button doesn't change

Comment: @Jack23

`{this.state.wasButtonClicked == true ? <Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" /> : <Submit   onSubmit={self.props.handleSubmit(values => {this.setState({wasButtonClicked: true}),self._onSubmit(values)})}   />}
            />
    }`


Use that without curly brackets



`this.state.wasButtonClicked == true ? <Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" /> : <Submit   onSubmit={self.props.handleSubmit(values => {this.setState({wasButtonClicked: true}),self._onSubmit(values)})}   />`

Comment: without curly brackets it prints "this.state.wasButtonClicked == true ? "

Comment: `Content = props => {
    return(
     //
          {this.state.wasButtonClicked == true ? <Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" /> : <Submit   onSubmit={self.props.handleSubmit(values => {this.setState({wasButtonClicked: true}),self._onSubmit(values)})}   />}
            />
    }` 

Why do you have this last ending angle bracket? Remove `/>` that please then it will correct the code and instead add a parenthesis `)`
@Jack23

Comment: @Jack23 Please refer to the above answer EDITED part. Thanks!